# Canvas App not showing in Chatter in Lightning UI

Tags: lightning-experience, chatter, canvas

I have created a Canvas App and I have enabled it for everything including Chatter. I am able to preview the Canvas App and it also shows up as a Quick Action. However, while in SF Classic I can see my app in the left hand panel of the Chatter tab I can't see it in the Lightning UI.

Canvas App showing in Classic UI:
[image: Classic UI]

But not in LEX:
[image: Lightning UI]

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Do you get any errors on your browser's Developer Console? Does a space for it appear but nothing shows up? Some more details would be nice.

Comment: @sfdcfox No errors and no empty spaces!